# Replacing NSAttributedString in NSTextStorage Moves NSTextView Cursor

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nstextview, nstextstorage

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5960-text-kit-tutorial-getting-started) and created a Mac version of it. It works pretty well, except there's a bug I can't figure out. The cursor jumps to the end of the string if you try editing anything in the middle of the string. Like this:

[image: NSTextView Cursor Jumps to End]

Here is a [sample project](https://d.pr/f/7nGAjp), or you can just create a new macOS project and put this in the default **ViewController.swift**:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {
  var textView: NSTextView!
  var textStorage: FancyTextStorage!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createTextView()
  }

  func createTextView() {
    // 1
    let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)]
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "This is a *cool* sample.", attributes: attrs)
    textStorage = FancyTextStorage()
    textStorage.append(attrString)

    let newTextViewRect = view.bounds

    // 2
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()

    // 3
    let containerSize = CGSize(width: newTextViewRect.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let container = NSTextContainer(size: containerSize)
    container.widthTracksTextView = true
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(container)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    // 4
    textView = NSTextView(frame: newTextViewRect, textContainer: container)
    textView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(textView)

    // 5
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
  }

}
```

And then create a **FancyTextStorage** class that subclasses `NSTextStorage` with this:

```
class FancyTextStorage: NSTextStorage{
  let backingStore = NSMutableAttributedString()
  private var replacements: [String: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]] = [:]

  override var string: String {
    return backingStore.string
  }
  override init() {
    super.init()
    createHighlightPatterns()
  }

  func createHighlightPatterns() {
    let boldAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)]
    replacements = ["(\\*\\w+(\\s\\w+)*\\*)": boldAttributes]
  }

  func applyStylesToRange(searchRange: NSRange) {
    let normalAttrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.init(calibratedRed: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)]

    addAttributes(normalAttrs, range: searchRange)

    // iterate over each replacement
    for (pattern, attributes) in replacements {
      do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        regex.enumerateMatches(in: backingStore.string, range: searchRange) {
          match, flags, stop in
          // apply the style
          if let matchRange = match?.range(at: 1) {
            print("Matched pattern: \(pattern)")
            addAttributes(attributes, range: matchRange)

            // reset the style to the original
            let maxRange = matchRange.location + matchRange.length
            if maxRange + 1 < length {
              addAttributes(normalAttrs, range: NSMakeRange(maxRange, 1))
            }
          }
        }
      }
      catch {
        print("An error occurred attempting to locate pattern: " +
              "\(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
  }

  func performReplacementsForRange(changedRange: NSRange) {
    var extendedRange = NSUnionRange(changedRange, NSString(string: backingStore.string).lineRange(for: NSMakeRange(changedRange.location, 0)))
    extendedRange = NSUnionRange(changedRange, NSString(string: backingStore.string).lineRange(for: NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(changedRange), 0)))
    beginEditing()
    applyStylesToRange(searchRange: extendedRange)
    endEditing()
  }

  override func processEditing() {
    performReplacementsForRange(changedRange: editedRange)
    super.processEditing()
  }

  override func attributes(at location: Int, effectiveRange range: NSRangePointer?) -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] {
    return backingStore.attributes(at: location, effectiveRange: range)
  }

  override func replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with str: String) {
    print("replaceCharactersInRange:\(range) withString:\(str)")

    backingStore.replaceCharacters(in: range, with:str)
    edited(.editedCharacters, range: range,
          changeInLength: (str as NSString).length - range.length)
  }

  override func setAttributes(_ attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?, range: NSRange) {
    //print("setAttributes:\(String(describing: attrs)) range:\(range)")
    backingStore.setAttributes(attrs, range: range)
    edited(.editedAttributes, range: range, changeInLength: 0)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  required init?(pasteboardPropertyList propertyList: Any, ofType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) {
    fatalError("init(pasteboardPropertyList:ofType:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

It seems that when the string is rewritten, it doesn't preserve the cursor position, but this same code on iOS (from the above-mentioned tutorial) doesn't have this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Save the selected range of the text view.  When you are finished with the attributed thing, put the saved text range back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I (hopefully) figured it out after reading this article: https://christiantietze.de/posts/2017/11/syntax-highlight-nstextstorage-insertion-point-change/

Within my **ViewController.swift**, I added the `textDidChange` delegate method and reusable function for updating the styles:

```
func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
  updateStyles()
}

func updateStyles(){
  guard let fancyTextStorage = textView.textStorage as? FancyTextStorage else { return }

  fancyTextStorage.beginEditing()
  fancyTextStorage.applyStylesToRange(searchRange: fancyTextStorage.extendedRange)
  fancyTextStorage.endEditing()
}
```

Then within the **FancyTextStorage**, I have to *remove* `performReplacementsForRange` from `processEditing()` because it calls `applyStylesToRange()` and the point of the aforementioned article is that **you can't apply styles within `TextStorage`'s `processEditing()` function** or else the world will explode (and the cursor will move to the end).

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I'd like to add that not only the world will explode :)  but the NSLayoutManager will probably get the union of the original user edited range (where text and attributes change) and the syntax-highlighted range (where only attributes change). The cursor is moved on the `.editedCharacters`, and the union of affected ranges lumps together both changes into a single `editMask` of `[.editedCharacters, .editedAttributes]`.

Comment: It does. Had the exact same issue. I used this one as a sample. https://github.com/mattrighetti/SimpleCodeEditor and re wrote it for Mac, and had the exact same issue.